# How to include libphonenumber (Google Phone library) in Visualforce

Tags: visualforce, google

I am working on including google libphonenumber in the visualforce page to validate any phone number. When i downloaded the library from github, the size of file is more than 15 mb. As you know, we can include 5 mb size of file in static resource. I want to refer only javscript not java one in the visualforce. How do we handle this. Can anyshare share your experience. Can you share the piece of vf page where you included libphonenumber related file.

Basically I want to use isValidNumber method from libphonenumber.

Comment: @sfdcfox , thanks, in the previous post, you mentioned that demo-compiled.js will work. Did you delete those posts because that is not the correct answer ?

Comment: I deleted it two hours ago... I'm not sure if it is correct, and I'd rather someone else answer that can confirm if it works.

Comment: Check this JS library, it is based on libphonenumber. https://github.com/Gilshallem/phoneparser

Comment: @SarojBera, Thansk for your reply. the above js library is for parsing phonenumber but I want to use isValidNumber method from libphonenumber .

Answer (score 2):

We have ported the [libphonenumber](https://appexchange.salesforce.com/appxListingDetail?listingId=a0N3A00000G12oJUAR) library to Salesforce (Apex) and it's available for free on the App Exchange. You can use it to validate the phone number. I'm one of the authors of the library, so I can help you out in case you'll have any questions.